# Warum erhalten Zahlwörter manchmal das Suffix „-e“?

Tags: idiom, history, colloquial, numbers, grammar-identification

Es gibt seltene Varianten, in denen Zahlwörter ein Suffix *-e* erhalten:

> Sie streckten alle **viere** von sich.
>   Beim Kegeln fielen alle **neune**.
>   Ach, du grüne **Neune!**
>   Wir treffen uns um **Zwölfe**.

Mein Eindruck ist, dass dies nur in Redewendungen, umgangssprachlich oder im Dialekt (letztes Beispiel) vorkommt. Stimmt dieser Eindruck und war das früher anders? Welche Regeln stecken (oder steckten) hinter diesen auf *-e* endenden Zahlwörtern?

Comment: In Österreich jedoch sind die Zahlwörter männlich (und es wird in vielen Fällen die Endung *-er* angehängt).: »Ich habe einen Einser bekommen.« (Schule); »Sie ist mit dem Fünfer gefahren« (Straßenbahn) (Siehe: Das österreichische Deutsch, Robert Sedlaczek, ISBN 3-8000-7075-8, S.89)

Comment: Das Buch von Sedlaczek ist zwar gut, aber warum nicht gleich auf das offizielle, amtliche Standardwerk verweisen? Österreichisches Wörterbuch, herausgegeben vom Bundesministerium für Unterricht, Kunst und Kultur. Seit wenigen Tagen (seit 1.6.2012) in der 42. Auflage erhältlich: ISBN: 978-3-209-07361-7 (Umfang: 1056 Seiten)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Der Duden hilft wie immer. Eine e-Endung deutet, bis auf wenige Ausnahmen (Junge, Kaese u. A.), auf ein feminines Substantiv hin. Zahlsubstantive sind ausnahmslos feminin. Ich nehme an, dass die Endung schlicht verloren ging.

> Bei den Zahlwörtern von zwei bis zwölf waren früher bei
>   substantivischem Gebrauch die Formen auf -e durchaus gebräuchlich,
>   heute beschränken sie sich auf Redewendungen wie alle viere von sich
>   strecken, alle neune werfen, fünf[e] gerade sein lassen und auf den
>   Gebrauch in Dialekten (vor fünfe aufstehen, vor zwölfe schlafen
>   gehen). Standardsprachlich ist nur die ungebeugte Form korrekt: Von
>   der Turmuhr schlug es zwölf (nicht: zwölfe). Nur zwei (nicht: zweie)
>   kehrten zurück.

http://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/sprachratgeber/beugung-von-zahlwoertern

Comment: Der Duden Artikel koennte allerdings ein bisschen ausfuehrlicher sein. Es waere zumindest interessant zu wissen, in welchen Dialekträumen das "e" erhalten blieb (mein Gefühl sagt, eher süddeutsch) und wann es aus der Mode kam...

Comment: Die Behauptung "Zahlsubstantive sind ausnahmslos feminin" ist falsch. In Österreich heißt es: "Ich habe auf meine Schularbeit einen Einser bekommen." oder "Mit welcher Straßenbahnlinie kommt man in den Prater? - Mit dem Einser."

Comment: Vielen Dank fuer den Hinweis zu den Oesterreichischen Dialekten. Wenn ich mich auf den Duden beziehe, dann impliziert das einen Bezug auf das Standarddeutsche. Das "ausnahmslos" bezieht sich somit auf alle Zahlwoerter, nicht auf alle Formen der deutschen Sprache. Also bitte nicht einfach sagen die Behauptung sei falsch.

Comment: Ich habe nicht von Dialekten gesprochen, sondern von österreichischem Deutsch. Österr. Deutsch ist kein Dialekt, sondern eine Standard-Varietät der Deutschen Sprache. Der Duden ist seit 1996 kein Standardwerk irgendeiner Sprache mehr. Die in Deutschland gesprochene Varietät der deutschen Hochsprache hat kein Standardwerk mehr. Das amtliche Standardwerk der österreichischen Varietät der deutschen Hochsprache ist das Österreichische Wörterbuch. Dort steht (Ausgabe 39 von 2001, Seite 170): Ein|ser (1er) der, -s/-: die Ziffer 1; einen E. hinschreiben; als Note einen E. (ein Sehr gut) bekommen.

Comment: Wikipedia: Österreichisches Deutsch. Beachte den Abschnitt "Zahlen, Uhrzeit": http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Österreichisches_Deutsch - geographische Verteilung der Varietäten der deutschen Sprache ohne Beachtung von Dialekten: http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/81/Sprachvarietäten_Deutsch.png

Comment: Okay. Ich ziehe meinen Einwand zurueck :)

Comment: Bei Uhrzeiten spricht man im Schwäbischen häufig ein "e" mit: http://www.schwaebisch-schwaetza.de/zahlen_und_zeiten.html

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Das mit dem Einser stimmt schon, den kennt man so auch in Bayern. Der Duden hat hier aber sicherlich nur die Zahlwörter *ohne* -er-Suffix gemeint, wie die Eins, die Zwei, etc. Finde mir einen Kontext, in dem im Österreichischen eine solche Zahl maskulin ist, und ich ziehe meinen Einwand gegen deinen Einwand zurück ;)

Comment: @Jules Auch im Bairischen werden Uhrzeiten mit -e am Ende ausgesprochen – aber nur von viere bis zwölfe. Es heißt also »Drei ist« aber »Viere ist«.