# Sind die beiden Formen korrekt: "mit euch drei/mit euch dreien"?

Tags: grammar, numbers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Warum erhalten Zahlwörter manchmal das Suffix “-e”?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/4242/warum-erhalten-zahlworter-manchmal-das-suffix-e)

Vor kurzem habe ich irgendwo den Ausdruck "*über euch dreien*" gelesen. Ich würde in demselben Satz "*über euch drei*" benutzen. Es gibt mehrere ähnliche Ausdrücke und wenn ich im Internet gesucht habe, habe ich beide Formen gefunden.

Sind diese beiden Formen korrekt? Gibt es einen grammatischen Unterschied zwischen den beiden?

---

Recently I've seen somewhere the phrase "*über euch dreien*". I would have used "*über euch drei*" in the same sentence. There are several similar phrases and I found both forms when I was searching on Internet.

Are both forms correct? Is there some grammar difference between the two?

---

Weitere Beispiele/more examples:

- über euch drei/dreien Google Books:
  [1](http://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&hl=en&q=%22%C3%BCber+euch+drei%22)
  [2](http://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&hl=en&q=%22%C3%BCber+euch+drei%22)
- mit euch zwei/zweien Google Books: [1](http://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&hl=en&q=%22mit+euch+zweien%22)
  [2](http://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&hl=en&q=%22mit+euch+zwei%22)
- bei euch drei/dreien Google Books:
  [1](http://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&hl=en&q=%22bei+euch+dreien%22)
  [2](http://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&hl=en&q=%22bei+euch+drei%22)

Comment: You inserted two times the link to the Google Books links for "über euch drei", but "über euch dreien" does indeed result only one time, so it's a meaningless example. Bummer.